# How to get localStorage item count (by value) into a local variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I load a page which holds a different url name at the end, I set up a localStorage item, which holds the value `activeGameSession`:

```
var pageUrl = window.location.href,
pageUrlParts = pageUrl.split("/"),
gameUrl = pageUrlParts[pageUrlParts.length-1],
activeGames = [];

if (gameArea.length) {
    var gameList = Object.values(localStorage);

    localStorage.setItem('game_' +  gameUrl, 'activeGameSession');

    for (var i = 0; i < gameList.length; i++) {
        if (gameList[i] === 'activeGameSession') {
            activeGames.push(gameList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In the **Application** tab of my browser, it clearly shows that I have **2 items** with that value in my localStorage, but when I log the `activeGames` array in my console, it says that I have only **1 item** in my array.

e.g. When I get 1 item in my array, and load another page, it should add one more `active` item to my local array, just as localStorage holds 2 items, but it does not, it only adds 1.

```
console.log(activeGames);
["active"]
```

When I should have:

```
console.log(activeGames);
["active", "active"]
```

Why is this happening, and how can I bypass this issue?

Comment: `$(location).attr('href')` - Why do you wrap `window.location` in a jQuery object? `var pageUrl = window.location.href`

Comment: @Andreas , thanks, duely noted. I already changed it.